# How to make counting labels in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 counting labels
i.e. label1 and label 2

I want to start count from 0 to label count value in fixed duration.

I have tried using timer, but labels are not set in same time.

Code I have tried

```
let label1Value = 20
let label2Value = 30 

var label1Count = 0
var label2Count = 0

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
  if label1Count > label1Value && label2Count > label2Value {
    timer.invalidate()
   } 
  if label1Count <= label1Value {
     label1.text = label1Count
     label1Count += 1
  }
  
  if label2Count <= label2Value {
     label2.text = label2Count
     label2Count += 1
  }
}
```

Help me if anything present to make counting labels same time in fixed duration

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and of course show a minimal complete code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try moving the changes, to `label2.text` and `label1.text`, inside a common `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` in order to update the view state in a safer way.

Comment: You only need one variable for the counting

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do this with one `Timer`. Use a separate  `scheduledTimer` object for each label.

```
    
    let label1Value = 20.0
    let label2Value = 30.0

    var label1Count = 0.0
    var label2Count = 0.0
    
    let duration = 10.0 //This is the duration u want to finish within

     let timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: duration/label1Value, repeats: true) {t in
        if self.label1Count <= self.label1Value {
            self.l1.text = "\(Int(self.label1Count))"
            self.label1Count += 1
        }
    }
        
    let timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: duration/label2Value, repeats: true) {t in
        if self.label2Count <= self.label2Value {
            self.l2.text = "\(Int(self.label2Count))"
            self.label2Count += 1
       }
    }
```